# vue render function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I extracted collapse transition form element.eleme.io for testing.
However, the code does not work as expected. The render function was called, but the methods provided by class Transition did not being used.
Tried to google how to use the render function correctly, but not much information about it. Anyone know how to solve the iusse?

> collapse-tranisition.js

```
class Transition {
  beforeEnter (el) {
    el.classList.add('collapse-transition')
    if (!el.dataset) el.dataset = {}

    el.dataset.oldPaddingTop = el.style.paddingTop
    el.dataset.oldPaddingBottom = el.style.paddingBottom

    el.style.height = '0'
    el.style.paddingTop = 0
    el.style.paddingBottom = 0
  }

  enter (el) {
    el.dataset.oldOverflow = el.style.overflow
    if (el.scrollHeight !== 0) {
      el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
      el.style.paddingTop = el.dataset.oldPaddingTop
      el.style.paddingBottom = el.dataset.oldPaddingBottom
    } else {
      el.style.height = ''
      el.style.paddingTop = el.dataset.oldPaddingTop
      el.style.paddingBottom = el.dataset.oldPaddingBottom
    }

    el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  }

  afterEnter (el) {
    el.classList.remove('collapse-transition')
    el.style.height = ''
    el.style.overflow = el.dataset.oldOverflow
  }

  beforeLeave (el) {
    if (!el.dataset) el.dataset = {}
    el.dataset.oldPaddingTop = el.style.paddingTop
    el.dataset.oldPaddingBottom = el.style.paddingBottom
    el.dataset.oldOverflow = el.style.overflow

    el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  }

  leave (el) {
    if (el.scrollHeight !== 0) {
      el.classList.add('collapse-transition')
      el.style.height = 0
      el.style.paddingTop = 0
      el.style.paddingBottom = 0
    }
  }

  afterLeave (el) {
    el.classList.remove('collapse-transition')
    el.style.height = ''
    el.style.overflow = el.dataset.oldOverflow
    el.style.paddingTop = el.dataset.oldPaddingTop
    el.style.paddingBottom = el.dataset.oldPaddingBottom
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'MyCollapseTransition',
  functional: true,
  render (h, { children }) {
    const data = {
      on: new Transition()
    }

    return h('transition', data, children)
  }
}
```

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <collapse-transition>
      <div v-show="show">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </collapse-transition>
    <button @click="show = !show">Show</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CollapseTransition from './utils/collapse-transition'

export default {
  components: {
    CollapseTransition
  },
  data () {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.collapse-transition {
  transition: 0.3s height ease-in-out, 0.3s padding-top ease-in-out, 0.3s padding-bottom ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `on` property expects a plain object, not a class instance.  To be precise, Vue uses `for .. in` to loop over the properties of that object, and that doesn't work on class methods.

Why would you even use a class here?

Comment: Honestly, the js file was directly extract from element. not quite sure why their source code did this. But if I use element directly in my project, it works fine.